# Помогите исправить ошибку при создании DB

Tags: java, postgresql

У меня метод создает базу:

`Connection` который приходит в метод он указывает на корень базы `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432`. Мой метод должен сначала создать базу `auto_services` и он успешно это делает, но вот потом он должен перейти в эту базу `connection.setCatalog("auto_services");` и выполнить скрипты создания таблиц. Но таблицы создаются не в базе `auto_services`(хотя она создается тут все ок) а в корне. Из чего понятно что не происходит перехода в подкаталог `auto_services`, либо объекты `createTasks` и `createComments` не видят этого перехода.

Скрипты лежат в `script`.

Помогите пожалуйста поправить код что-бы таблицы создавались в `auto_services`.

```
public void createDB(final Connection connection) {

    final String[] script = this.property.getCreateDBScripts();

    try {

        final PreparedStatement createDatabase =
                connection.prepareStatement(script[0]);


        createDatabase.executeUpdate();

        connection.setCatalog("auto_services"); // полагаю проблема здесь но я уже что только туда не сувал(((

        final PreparedStatement createTasks =
                connection.prepareStatement(script[1]);

        final PreparedStatement createComments =
                connection.prepareStatement(script[2]);


        createTasks.executeUpdate();
        createComments.executeUpdate();

        createComments.close();
        createTasks.executeUpdate();
        createDatabase.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать дисконект от базы. и потом сразу приконектится, только с указанием базы. тут: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432`

Comment: @Tsyklop с созданием нового соединения понятно как сделать просто Connection новый создать и все. А вот как в рамках одного соединения между каталогами переместится..?

Comment: ничего не нашел в гугле по этому поводу.

Comment: @Tsyklop та же фигня(((